# What does "where for" mean in Rust?

Tags: rust

This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853421/11140945) uses a `where` syntax I'm unfamiliar with:

```rust
fn readfile<'a, T: ?Sized>(filename: &str) -> Result<Box<Outer<'a, T>>, Box<std::error::Error>>
where
    for<'de> T: Deserialize<'de> + 'a
{
   ...
```

What does the `for` mean?

Where is this documented?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is so-called [higher-ranked trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html):

> for<'a> can be read as "for all choices of 'a"

And it is defined by [Rust RFC 0387](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0387-higher-ranked-trait-bounds.md).