# How do I dynamically create a struct from a string from input?

Tags: rust

Given a situation where we receive inputs for some nodes type like 'nodeA' or 'nodeB', and we want to initialize structs with that same input. Is it possible without a gigantic switch block? These structs share similar behaviour (using a Trait for that) but with some differences.

```
pub trait Executable {
    fn run(&self);
}

pub struct NodeA {}

impl Executable for NodeA {
    fn run(&self) {}
}

pub struct NodeB {}

impl Executable for NodeB {
    fn run(&self) {}
}
```

Flow:

```
User inputs 'nodeA'

Program initializes struct nodeA with some data

User inputs 'nodeB'

Program initializes struct nodeB with some data

...
```

To specify better, the final use case is reading a JSON file with all the nodes and respective params to be instantiated. Some of those nodes can come from external plugins, so the number of existing nodes can become very big.

Comment: There are many ways to initialize data. Will every `NodeA` be constructed the same way as every other `NodeA`? If so, you just need an associated method that will set it up, and your `match` statement doesn't have to do anything besides delegate a constructor. It's hard to give specific advice without knowing your use case.

Comment: So I guess there will be *many* nodes? Otherwise I don't see the problem with a `match - case`, or how you call it, a `switch` block (which is how it's called in most other languages).

Comment: @JeremyMeadows Yap, the final use case it that there will be lots of nodes, some of them coming from external plugins (a future use case), so a `match - case` block would not scale well.

Comment: If your JSON has a set schema, you should use the `serde` crate to parse it. That will automatically populate all the data, the only thing you'd have to maintain is a single struct that matched your JSON layout.

Comment: The only alternative that I know would be a registry type thing, combined with a factory pattern.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows I'm already doing that but is translating to a Node struct that is general. Can serde use a json parameter to map to a specific struct?

Comment: @Finomnis Could you point me to an example in Rust, please? I'm more used to OOP and I'm still wrapping my head around Rust traits and enums

Comment: serde can handle generics, although I haven't personally used them before. you might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851996/rust-and-serde-deserializing-using-generics. If you can create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data and struct definitions in the playground, I bet we could figure something out.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows First of all, thank you for your help.
Currently my solution looks something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d1d554416257d0ca6b76f22adb5b68f
Using serde with Enum I can get it to work fine - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=120b8931990bf9b3d68d78ebca7d54b1 - but I can't see how this can be extended with more nodes later, and the code will extend a lot. Also, if I want to run specific logic for each type, will need a match-case
 as well, right?

Comment: I don't think your approach is too bad; you have a single struct to define each collection of data. It is hard to reduce more than that. However, since your enum variants share several fields, you can replace those chunks with a `#[serde(flatten)]` struct so that when you create a new variant, you can reuse some of it: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=06bceb2ed37ffd0271ec5ea3c4fb95e8). Sorry that wasn't more help, but you should be able to add more nodes to that enum and shouldn't have to change anything else.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows Thank you very much, that simplifies a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For smaller, static number of nodes, I think a `match` - `case` construct is perfectly fine.

But if you have a larger number of nodes, or the available nodes is dynamically changing, I would implement something like this:

```rust
pub trait Executable {
    fn run(&self);
}

pub struct NodeA {}

impl Executable for NodeA {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("NodeA::run()");
    }
}

pub struct NodeB {}

impl Executable for NodeB {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("NodeB::run()");
    }
}

pub trait Matcher {
    fn try_match(&self, s: &str) -> Option<Box<dyn Executable>>;
}

pub struct NodeAMatcher;
pub struct NodeBMatcher;

impl Matcher for NodeAMatcher {
    fn try_match(&self, s: &str) -> Option<Box<dyn Executable>> {
        (s == "NodeA").then(|| Box::new(NodeA {}) as Box<dyn Executable>)
    }
}
impl Matcher for NodeBMatcher {
    fn try_match(&self, s: &str) -> Option<Box<dyn Executable>> {
        (s == "NodeB").then(|| Box::new(NodeB {}) as Box<dyn Executable>)
    }
}

struct MatcherRegistry {
    matchers: Vec<Box<dyn Matcher>>,
}

impl MatcherRegistry {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { matchers: vec![] }
    }
    fn register_matcher(&mut self, matcher: impl Matcher + 'static) {
        self.matchers.push(Box::new(matcher));
    }
    fn try_get_node(&self, s: &str) -> Option<Box<dyn Executable>> {
        self.matchers
            .iter()
            .filter_map(|matcher| matcher.try_match(s))
            .next()
    }

    fn try_execute(&self, s: &str) {
        if let Some(node) = self.try_get_node(s) {
            node.run();
        } else {
            println!("'{}' not found.", s);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut registry = MatcherRegistry::new();

    registry.register_matcher(NodeAMatcher);
    registry.register_matcher(NodeBMatcher);

    registry.try_execute("NodeA");
    registry.try_execute("NodeB");
    registry.try_execute("NodeC");
}
```

```
NodeA::run()
NodeB::run()
'NodeC' not found.
```

Here, you have a [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

The structs `NodeAMatcher` and `NodeBMatcher` are factories for `NodeA` and `NodeB`. They can check if the input matches, and then create an `Executable` object.

Then, you collect all possible factories (or `Matcher`s here) in a registry, here called `MatcherRegistry`. You can then, at runtime, add or remove matchers as you wish.

---

Of course, if you don't need to create a new object every time and the act of executing doesn't consume it, you can reduce the complexity a little by bypassing the factory pattern:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Executable {
    fn run(&self);
}

pub struct NodeA {}

impl Executable for NodeA {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("NodeA::run()");
    }
}

pub struct NodeB {}

impl Executable for NodeB {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("NodeB::run()");
    }
}

struct ExecutableRegistry {
    executables: HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn Executable>>,
}

impl ExecutableRegistry {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            executables: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
    fn register_executable(
        &mut self,
        command: &'static str,
        executable: impl Executable + 'static,
    ) {
        self.executables.insert(command, Box::new(executable));
    }

    fn try_execute(&self, s: &str) {
        if let Some(node) = self.executables.get(s) {
            node.run();
        } else {
            println!("'{}' not found.", s);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut registry = ExecutableRegistry::new();

    registry.register_executable("NodeA", NodeA {});
    registry.register_executable("NodeB", NodeB {});

    registry.try_execute("NodeA");
    registry.try_execute("NodeB");
    registry.try_execute("NodeC");
}
```

Of course there exists a large mount of other variations of the same patterns. Which one you implement is up to you and your usecase.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to implement something similar with the HashMap but could not figure out that logic related to the Box. Makes sense since we don't know at runtime the space that it will take. Thank you again, will experiment a variation of this

Comment: @lowkey_daisy at *compile time ;)

Comment: Oops, my bad :D

Comment: Instead of using a new factory struct I would just use a closure coerced to a function pointer and store `HashMap<&'static str, fn() -> Box<dyn Executable>>`, or even `Vec<(&'static str, fn() -> Box<dyn Executable>)>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Can `fn` have data attached to it? Like, a capturing closure? Because to my knowledge `fn` can only be static function pointers, which would not be compatible with his use case of loading it at runtime. Although `HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn Fn() -> Box<dyn Executable>>>` would probably work.

Comment: @Finomnis The function will get the data as parameters and instantiate the object.

Comment: But yah, I agree that there are many different ways to implement the basic idea behind this. Both factory structs and factory closures are valid imo.